# Main difference between a Web application and Windows universal application

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I am new in APPs development and would like to understand the main difference between a Web APP and a universal windows APP?

Comment: Do you really mean a (server based) Web Application or a HTML based device App? The question isn't that clear or precise, maybe tell us what you want to us the App for.

Comment: Server based Web App!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web application is basically website which you open in web browser, UWP application is windows application which you download from store.

For example, www.stackoverflow.com is web application. [Word Mobile](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/word-mobile/9wzdncrfjb9s#)  is UWP aplication.

Answer (score 1):

**Web applications** are websites that you can open through browsers.

**UWP** is a native windows application which you can run on all Windows 10 devices (tablets, phone, desktop, IOT, etc.) You can also embed web applications inside UWP using `WebView`.